# 3 bit synchronous counter design d flip flop

Tags: flipflop, counter

Any idea how I would go about designing a 3 bit  synchronous counter in regards to having the following states

```
111->001->110->101->100->000->010->111
```

I drew up a present state and next state table etc... not really sure where to go from here, I have designed in logism a start schematic with a CLK, CLR and PRE, with 3 D type Flip flops as these are the ones I am required to use, but I am unsure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing is to treat each bit individually.

For example, for the low-order bit, lets call it `next_state[0]`.

```
state     | next_state[0]
---------------
   000    | 0
   001    | 0
   010    | 1
   011    | X
   100    | 0
   101    | 0
   110    | 0
   111    | 1
```

So you can write

`next_state[0] = state[0] &  state[1] & state[2] | ~state[0] & state[1] & ~state[2]`

If you are building this with discrete logic you could simplify this to

`next_state[0] = state[1] & (state[0] & state[2] | ~state[0] & ~state[2])`

And you have an equation you can use to drive the flip-flop that will generate the next condition for the low-bit of the state variable.

Finding the equations for the other two state bits works the same way.

Comment: i must be missing something, how do you know 010 = 1? i'm lost in regards to how you got that table

Comment: According to your question, when the current state is 010, the next state is 111, which means the low bit is 1.

Comment: can i use a 3 k maps for each different state?

Comment: Yes Karnaugh is the way to go here. Or a small microcontroller.

Comment: @Sim, one k-map for each bit of  `next_state` is enough.

Comment: yeah thats what i mean, 1 for each, don't worry i got it thanks for the help