# How should a counter with R-S flip-flops look?

Tags: vhdl, flipflop, counter

I tried to find on web something about counters with R-S flip-flops and I can't find anything.

How should they look?

As a particular counter I need one to obtain this sequence: 0, 1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 7.

Comment: What functions have you developed? Think of it as a synchronous design problem first then try to implement it in VHDL, as there are loads of examples out there for a RS Flip-Flop in VHDL, then all you'd need is some VHDL to link it up with your functions you derived by hand.

Comment: Why don't you use a regular binary 3 bit counter and some logic to convert the numbers 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 to 3, 2, 6, 4 and 5?

Comment: There was a very similar question asked previously: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/61117/3-bit-synchronous-counter-design-d-flip-flop

Answer (score 2):

As Andy points out use a 3 bit (stage) binary counter and logic gates to get the sequence. As I suspect this is a homework question I'll leave you with the logic gates to work out for yourself.

You can build a S-R flip flop from simple two input logic gates. I have shown an S-R type using two NOR gates and a NOT S-R type using NAND gates.

[image]

The problem is the simple S-R Flip flop (two cross coupled gates) cannot act as a counter (*divider*) by itself. Also if both inputs are HIGH (in the case of the S-R NOR flip flop) the output is uncertain.

By adding more logic gates around the S-R flip flop you can prevent this happening (*resolve the conflict*) and create a circuit capable of dividing an input pulse by two (*a one stage binary counter*). These circuits sense the current state of the outputs (*Q and notQ*) and 'steer' the next input pulse (clock) to the appropriate input on the flip flop causing the circuit to change state

A commonly used counter is the D type which uses TWO internally connected S-R flip flops. The 'not Q' output is connected to the D or Data input. By connecting up the D type flip flops as show below you can make a binary counter any length required. For this problem you need three stages (Binary 000 - 111, Decimal 0 - 7). All that you need to do is work out the logic required to change the binary count sequence to the sequence you require.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your diagrams show a T-latch and a bunch of D-flip-flops, but OP said he's specifically interested in RS-flip-flops.

Comment: I meant to put in a JK but the point I was trying to get across is that a simple RS flip flip without something around it isn't a counter per se. The circuit shows the internal structure that incorporated the R-S flip flop. The question asks about counts **with** flip flops - a D type contains two R-S type flip flops as shown in the internal circuit. It would be possible from the information I have posted to build his own S-R flip flop divider circuit using external logic gates using this design. I won't give a full answer to homework - just set him on the path. So a bit harsh to deduct points