# Sequential logic counters

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, counter

I have an assignment to create a counter that counts in the following way depending on input ***y***

if y = 0 -> 0, 6, 3, 2, 1, 0...

if y = 1 -> 0, 5, 4, 7, 2, 1, 0...

Also it has another input ***x*** if x = 0 it counts up (for example 0,6,3,2,1,0) and if x = 1 it counts down (0,1,2,3,6,0).

I know that i can solve this by creating a big table with following columns

```
x|y|Q1|Q2|Q3||Q1+|Q2+|Q3+
----------------------------
0|0|0 |0 |0 || 1 | 1 |0
0|0|0 |0 |1 || 0 | 0 |0
0|0|0 |1 |0 || 0 | 0 |1
0|0|0 |1 |1 || 0 | 1 |0
```

...

But is there any simpler (and more elegant ) solution?

*I can only use JK flip-flops. This is sequential logic so i don't have to worry about voltage or things like that... Also if it means something we use HADES for this*

Comment: I think you need to carry out your big table a little bit further to show you've put your sweat into your homework before someone hands you an answer.

Comment: A near-duplicate question (with unfortunately no useful answers): http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/70623/how-should-a-counter-with-r-s-flip-flops-look

Comment: Another near duplicate question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/61117/3-bit-synchronous-counter-design-d-flip-flop This one has an answer that will at least help you set up the answer, although it doesn't address how to synthesize the result with JK FF's.

Comment: And yet another duplicate: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/69020/easy-resource-to-learn-solving-counter-problems (again for D FFs not JK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The "trick" with JK flip-flops

Since we don't have a previous answer about designing state machines with JK flip-flops...

Designing with JK flip-flops is pretty much the same as design with D flip-flops (or T flip-flops or any other kind of flip-flops.)  But with the JK flip-flop the excitation table is such that there is a trick that makes dealing with the state transition logic slightly simpler.

For any state machine/counter design you need the [*excitation table*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excitation_table) for your particular flip flop.

For JK flip flops the excitation table looks like

```
Previous State -> Present State    J K
0 -> 0                             0 X
0 -> 1                             1 X
1 -> 0                             X 1
1 -> 1                             X 0
```

The special property we are going to leverage is that when the previous state is `0` then the `K` input is a don't care, and when the previous state is `1` then the `J` input is always a don't care.

First you have to complete your table.  Not only do you have to have the inputs and the `Q`s, you also need all the `J` and `K` entries:

```
x|y|Q1|Q2|Q3||Q1+|Q2+|Q3+||J1|K1|J2|K2|J3|K3
--------------------------------------------
0|0|0 |0 |0 || 1 | 1 |0  ||1 |X |...
0|0|0 |0 |1 || 0 | 0 |0  ||0 |X |
0|0|0 |1 |0 || 0 | 0 |1  ||0 |X |
0|0|0 |1 |1 || 0 | 1 |0  ||0 |X |
...
```

Now we need to draw the 6 K-Maps for `J1`,`K1`,`J2`,`K2`,`J3`, and `K3`.  If we weren't using our "trick" we would need these to be 5-variable maps (`x`,`y`,`Q1`,`Q2`, and `Q3`).

But because `J1` is don't care whenever `Q1` is 1 we only need to do the map for `J1` for the case that `Q1` is 0.  And of course, in that case we know that `Q1` is 0, so we can just do a *4* variable map (with input variables `x`,`y`,`Q2`, and `Q3`).